# total by rows of pivot table

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have the following data frame (csv)

```
item_group item_code  total_qty  total_amount        cost_center
0           Drink   IC06-1P          1         3.902  Cafe II
1           Drink    IC09-1          1         2.927  Cafe II 
2       BreakFast    FS04-2          1         6.463  Cafe II
3           Drink    IC08-1          1         2.927  Cafe II
4           Drink    DT05-1          1         2.561  Cafe II
..            ...       ...        ...           ...                ...
79  Standard Food    FS01-2         12        83.412  Cafe II
80  Standard Food    FS01-1         13       101.465  Cafe II
81          Drink    IC05-1         14        54.628   Cafe I
82  Standard Food    FS01-2         35       243.285   Cafe I
83  Standard Food    FS01-1         44       343.420   Cafe I
```

I am trying to do a pivot

```
# Import pandas
import pandas as pd

# Reading CSV file

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

df1 = df.pivot_table(index=['item_group','item_code'],
                    columns=['cost_center'],
                    values=['total_qty','total_amount'],fill_value=0,
                    aggfunc='sum').swaplevel(axis=1).sort_index(level=0, axis=1)
    
out = df1.join(pd.concat({'total': df1.groupby(axis=1, level=1).sum()}, axis=1))
print(out)
```

Result

```
cost_center             Cafe I - 103cafe            ...        total          
                            total_amount total_qty  ... total_amount total_qty
item_group    item_code                             ...                       
Add Food      AD001                1.952         4  ...        1.952       4.0
              AD002                0.976         2  ...        0.976       2.0
              AD003                1.952         4  ...        1.952       4.0
              AD004                5.000         5  ...        5.000       5.0
              AD007                0.976         2  ...        0.976       2.0
...                                  ...       ...  ...          ...       ...
Standard Food FS01-2             243.285        35  ...      326.697      47.0
              FS01-2P             20.853         3  ...       27.804       4.0
              FS01-6               6.951         1  ...        6.951       1.0
              FS02-1              19.389         3  ...       25.852       4.0
              FS02-2               6.463         1  ...       25.852       4.0
```

Example, I want to calculate the `group_total` (total by each `item_group`)

```
cost_center                       Cafe I                   Cafe II \...
                            total_amount total_qty      total_amount   
item_group    item_code                                                
Add Food      AD001                1.952         4             0.000   
              AD002                0.976         2             0.000   
->group_total                      2.928         6             0.000
BreakFast     FN10-1               5.000         1             0.000   
              FN10-1P              5.000         1             0.000   
->group_total                      10.00         2             0.000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could take inspiration from this link

https://www.statology.org/pandas-pivot-table-subtotals/

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'team': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
                   'position': ['G', 'G', 'F', 'F', 'G', 'F', 'F', 'F'],
                   'all_star': ['Y', 'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'Y'],
                   'points': [4, 4, 6, 8, 9, 5, 5, 12]})
 
my_table = pd.pivot_table(df, values='points',
                              index=['team', 'all_star'],
                              columns='position',
                              aggfunc='sum')

pd.concat([
    y.append(y.sum().rename((x, 'Total')))
    for x, y in my_table.groupby(level=0)])
```

[image]